# is it possible to get guild owner tag in discord.js v13?

Tags: javascript, discord

i tried

```
const ownerId = guild.fetchOwner();
console.log(ownerId.tag)
```

i get undefined
same thing when im evaluating it
`message.guild.ownerId.tag`

list of testing eval

1. message.guild.ownertag = undefined
2. message.guild.ownerTag = undefined
3. message.guild.owner.tag = undefined
4. message.guild.owner.Tag = undefined
5. message.guild.ownerId.tag = undefined
6. message.guild.ownerId.Tag = undefined
7. message.guild.ownerId = (my_id/guild_owner_id)
8. message.guild.fetchOwner() = (<@my_id>/<@guild_owner_ID>)

please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also another way to fetch the owner if you want to do it synchronously. You can use `guild.ownerId` to get the id of the owner and then `guild.members.cache.get()` to get the owner. An example:

```js
const ownerId = guild.ownerId
const owner = guild.members.cache.get(ownerId)
console.log(owner.user.tag)
```

(Note: the owner might not be cached sometimes so `guild.members.cache.get()` might not return anything sometimes. I just posted this as an alternative to @Crytek1012's answer)

Answer (score 0):

`guild.fetchOwner()` returns a promise, you need to add `await`.

```
const ownerId = await guild.fetchOwner();
// also, you need to access the user property before trying to get the user tag
console.log(ownerId.user.tag);
```